# Call a function of external js file in angular 5 component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Under **index.html** I have delcared an external js file like
`<script data-siteid="XXXXXX" src="https://api.cartstack.com/js/customer-tracking/website.com_c7ee604471301b0bd028e8f19a535557.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>`

I have to call a function named **cartstack_updatecart()** from a component. (That function is generating from above link). How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps in your component:-

```
1) First add a reference of your external JS file for importing it to the component. 
   Import * as abcJS from '/YourExternalJS.js';

2) Now declare a "var" of the same name that your function has inside external JS.
   declare var cartstack_updatecart: any;

3) ngOninit(){
 cartstack_updatecart();
 }

4) Do remember that your JQuery should be loaded first than your external JS file.
```

I have called that function on ngoninit lifecycleHook.
Also instead of declaring external JS file inside Index.html, I would rather suggest you to declare it in angular-cli.json file in scripts array.
All the best.

Comment: @Dipankar Naskar
Have you got the solution or you still facing issues? Please let me know, I can share the code in more detail.

Comment: yeah I have tried your suggestion. and it's working. Thanks man.

Comment: Just quick note for me it worked without first step.. That just gave me error '../../yourExternalJS.js' is not a module (it worked but the error was in the bash).. and import in angular-cli.json was also required. So in my case, skip first step and add another step which is add script in angular-cli.json scripts..

Comment: Yes scripts can be included either via adding them to angular-cli.json or dropping their reference straight forward to Index.html.
I would also like to notify here that in angular 6, we don't have angular-cli.json.
CLI projects in angular 6 onwards will be using  angular.json instead of .angular-cli.json for build and project configuration.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekSharma, in my case JS file is deployed on another server. How can I achieve the same thing?

Comment: I added the external js file in angular.json file, but in that external file is the 3rd party js script file it having the all functions are self-invoked functions.
How can i get into component file.
This is the link jsfiddle for the external file example
`https://jsfiddle.net/kishore0207/e3L2xyo0/4/`
In component.ts file i need to call the function is 
affirm.checkout.open({
     success: function (card_details) {
       console.log('### affirm.checkout.open');
     },
     error: function (error_response) {
     },
     checkout_data: 'Object';
   });@AbhishekSharma
Thank you.