# How to call a javascript function from TypeScript in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to call a normal javascript function from a typescripit file.

Assume that i have a javascript file names test.js and i have imported this file in the index.html of the application.

Now I need to call this

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

function from Dashbord.component.ts file.

Comment: Using of jquery is not recommended with angular2+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623348/angular4-how-to-call-a-function-in-a-external-js  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346559/how-to-call-external-java-script-function-in-angular-5  or   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325235/call-a-function-of-external-js-file-in-angular-5-component

Comment: Thanks now I am able to do this