# Passing parameter onclick, in a loop using angular8

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, angular8, ngfor

I have an array of objects. i am iterating that in loop and passing each item's name to **onclick** which targets a function `openIt(val)` in `app.js` file which is in assets folder. ie

Angular Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listArray">
<button class="tabopen" onclick="openIt(item.name)">{{item.name}}</button>
</div>
```

app.js Code:

```
function openIt(data) {
console.log(data);
}
```

In my **openIt function** in app.js file i am not getting **item.name**. In my console it displays error that **item is not defined**. But when i pass static data i.e `onclick="openIt('sample_data')"`it does not show any error.

Even though item.name also exists i am getting correct values against this as well. I am not getting that why i am not able to pass iterative data to the parameters.

Comment: use (click)="function".

Comment: I want to target the function in my app.js file which is not in the same component. When i use (click) it looks for the openIt() in my .ts file and displays openIt is not a function

Comment: So basically you want to call a function of another component, You can use shared service See this example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service)

Comment: @SameerKhan no i want my component to communicate with a simple app.js file in my assets folder

Comment: @AhmadHabib are you using **angularJs** or **angular>=2**

Comment: @SameerKhan i am using angular6

Comment: Now I got your question, you have a **external/third party** library and want to invoke a function of that file - this answer can help you, take a look into it https://stackoverflow.com/a/51326209/11719787

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using `Angular` then you should go with `(click)` because when you declare an event handler you need to *surround* the `DOM` *event name* in `parentheses` and assign a [template statement](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-statements) to it.

```
<button class="tabopen" (click)="openIt(item.name)">{{item.name}}</button>
```

Comment: But, won't it look for the function in same component's TS file then? I want to target a function in app.js file due to some reasons

Comment: @AhmadHabib if the previous version works for you then this should work as well because I just change the event handler with angular version of `click`

Comment: I tired this but it says openIt() is not defined as it is looking for this function in same component. I am still wanting to target openIt() function in my app.js file located in assets folder.

Comment: @AhmadHabib, then you should declare a function in your current component which calls another function from app.js

Comment: That worked. I called a function in current component with (click) event and from that event i called openIt() that was in my app.js file.
Thank you so much mate. Much appreciation

Answer (score 2):

event binding: varsion 1 on-click="function", version 2 (click)="function"

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listArray">
<button class="tabopen" on-click="openIt(item.name)">{{item.name}}</button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of listArray">
<button class="tabopen" (click)="openIt(item.name)">{{item.name}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoc can also send item and get all properties of item in .ts file.

Html file:

```
<button class="tabopen" (click)="openIt(item)">{{item.name}}</button>
```

ts class:

```
 openIt(item){
        consol.log('item==>' , item)
    }
```